# How do i import the extracted Json data to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, json

I am  trying to fetch movie information from omdbapi.So far i have this code which is extracting data from imdb using omdb api.But i want import that data to my database.how do i accomplish that.

my code look like this

```
    <form>
<input type="text"  id="tst"/>
<input type="button" value="search"  id="btn"/>
</form>
<table class="table table-hover" id="imdb">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Poster</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Rated</th>
                <th>Runtime</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Director</th>
                <th>Actors</th>
                <th>Plot</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

This is jquery code i am using to fetch the movie information

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('#btn').click(function(){
              var imdbid=$('#tst').val();
               var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i="+imdbid+"&plot=short&r=json"
        $.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function (json) {
            var tr;
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td><img src=" + json.Poster + " width='200' height='297'></td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Title + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Year + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Rated + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Runtime + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Genre + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Director + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Actors + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json.Plot + "</td>");
        $('#imdb').append(tr);
        }
        })
              })
    });
```

Comment: You will have to write a server-side script that either connects to their API and saves it to the database, or accepts the info from your client-side and saves it to the database

Comment: Well actually what I want to accomplish is that .I want user to put the IMDb ID and search for the movie details which it is doing and allowed user to add some additional information and send the data to my phone script along with the data I have extracted from API ..I just need to know the process that's all

Comment: After getting the data from api and taking user input you can create an ajax call to post this data on server and you need to write a server side script where you can insert this data in database.

Comment: @AfshanShujat can you show me an example of how to send this extracted data along with user submitted information to php using ajax.a little bit of coding hint will be helpful.i am pretty lost right now.

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a json object from your api response(in same function where you are creating html).

```
 JSONData = JSON.stringify({
            "Title": Title,
            "Year": Year,
            "Rated" : Rated,
            ...........so on

        });
postDataToserver(JSONData);
```

And you can define your function to post data like -

```
function postDataToserver(JSONData)
    $.ajax({
        url: "your_server_script_path",
        type:"POST",
        data:JSONData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
```

If you want to send in simple post format not as JSON object then you don't need to use JSON.stringify and similarly in function remove contentype information. Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks this helps a lot :-).But one thing the data i am pulling from api is already in json format so i do not really need to use JSON.stringify() do i ?

Comment: no, then it is not required, you can pass the json object to postDataToserver function and can use json_encode at your server side script.

Comment: what if I want to push some text input values into the data I am pulling and send that to php on form submit .how do I push those input values into the json string I am getting from API ?

Comment: You can create one more json object for form data and can send two objects on different keys like -
{ api_data: data_1, form_data: data_2},

Comment: I was thinking of using Marge.is this reliable ??

Comment: i don't have about it, but i though you don't need to use an  extra plugin just remove the type json from ajax request and send these json object on server on two different keys and you can write your logic of json decoding at server end. If you are more comfortable with more. js and it is not affecting the performance then you can go ahead with that :)