# ajax return value to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The main purpose is to get the data changed in excel and return the data to certain URL,so I can update data into database.

I've got the value of changed data,the changed data is an array.

**How do I pass them to response and return to URL?**

Here is the code:

```
afterChange: function(source, changes) {
    var a;
    if (changes !== 'loadData') {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: 'url.com',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                //get data changed at row
                a = hot.getDataAtRow(source[0][0]);
                res = a;
                //console shows the value of res was changed to a;
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I have literally no idea what this person is asking..

Comment: i think you need specify data option in ajax call. Like a data: { dataChanged: hot.getDataAtRow(source[0][0]) }, if you need to send changed data

Comment: data and dataType are different. data - are data send to server, dataType are data what server return back.

Comment: You need to make another call to post the converted data to server inside the success callback of your first ajax call - see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904199/how-do-i-import-the-extracted-json-data-to-database/36929741#36929741

Answer (score 0):

I thought you need to make some modification in your code if you want to post data on server after converting it. First you convert it then send it to server.

```
afterChange: function(source, changes) {
    var a;
    if (changes !== 'loadData') {
        a = hot.getDataAtRow(source[0][0]);
        postDataToServer(a);
    }
}

function postDataToServer(a){
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: 'url.com',
            data: a,// JSON.stringify(a), if 'a' is an array
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {

                console.log(res);
            }
        });

}
```

Is your data is in JSON format? If not then you can convert an array into json format using JSON.stringify(a) and post it on server.